# I'm new to sql language and am learning so I can help my organization out with pulling data. How would I go about correcting the join error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to run this command for a couple days with no luck.

```
train> SELECT i.bill_cyc_cd, i.store_cd,
  2    SUM(CASE WHEN p.past_due_tp# > 0 AND p.past_due_tp# <= 4 THEN i.sch_pmt_amt ELSE 0 END) AS sch_pmt_amt,
  c.fname, c.lname, c.home_phone
FROM inst_cntr i
JOIN cntr$past_due_tp p ON i.cust_cd = p.cust_cd AND i.cntr_cd = p.cntr_cd
JOIN cust c ON i.cust_cd = c.cust_cd
WHERE i.bill_cyc_cd IN ('300', '150', '015', '030', '922', '921', '920')
  AND p.past_due_tp# > 0 AND p.past_due_tp# <= 4
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cntr$past_due_tp pd WHERE pd.cust_cd = i.cust_cd AND pd.cntr_cd = i.cntr_cd AND pd.past_due_tp# > 0 AND pd.past_due_tp# <= 4 AND pd.past_due_tp# IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY i.bill_cyc_cd, i.store_cd, c.fname, c.lname, c.home_phone;
  3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10  JOIN cntr$past_due_tp p ON i.cust_cd = p.cust_cd AND i.cntr_cd = p.cntr_cd
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

You can see the error I am running into at the bottom.

I tried formatting the join command differently but cannot get it to work because it looks right.

Answer (score 1):

you end the group by at the ; and after that continue with the

```
3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

and the random join

```
JOIN cntr$past_due_tp p ON i.cust_cd = p.cust_cd AND i.cntr_cd = p.cntr_cd
```

these two things can provide you the current error

the ideal way to pass this query is

```
SELECT
 i.bill_cyc_cd,
 i.store_cd,
 c.fname,
 c.lname,
 c.home_phone
 SUM(CASE WHEN p.past_due_tp# > 0 AND p.past_due_tp# <= 4 THEN i.sch_pmt_amt ELSE 0 END) AS sch_pmt_amt,
FROM
 inst_cntr i
 JOIN cntr$past_due_tp p ON i.cust_cd = p.cust_cd AND i.cntr_cd = p.cntr_cd
 JOIN cust c ON i.cust_cd = c.cust_cd
WHERE
  i.bill_cyc_cd IN ('300', '150', '015', '030', '922', '921', '920')
  AND p.past_due_tp# > 0 AND p.past_due_tp# <= 4
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cntr$past_due_tp pd
    WHERE
      pd.cust_cd = i.cust_cd
      AND pd.cntr_cd = i.cntr_cd
      AND pd.past_due_tp# > 0
      AND pd.past_due_tp# <= 4
      AND pd.past_due_tp# IS NOT NULL
    )
GROUP BY
  i.bill_cyc_cd,
  i.store_cd,
  c.fname,
  c.lname,
  c.home_phone
```

Comment: When I ran it just populated some random numbers in the middle and at the bottom and did not run. Is there a way to share a screen shot?

Comment: you can copy / paste the results here at the comments